# PDFBOX: Merge adds unused Fonts, how to remove it

Tags: java, pdfbox

i merge two PDF Files into one with PDFBOX Version 2. 
The First one got Fonts:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
XXMGEM+Arial-BoldMT                  TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     15  0
XXMGEM+ArialMT                       TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     19  0
XXMGEM+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     27  0
XXMGEM+ArialNarrow-Bold              TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     40  0
XXMGEM+ArialNarrow                   TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     44  0
```

and the Second one:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
UNTWVR+HelveticaLTCom-Roman          CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     25  0
UNTYID+HelveticaLTCom-Bold           CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     26  0
UNTZUP+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     27  0
UNUBHB+Arial-BoldMT                  CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     28  0
Helvetica-Bold                       Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  no      29  0
UNXPUH+HelveticaLTCom-Roman          CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     50  0
UNXRGT+HelveticaLTCom-Bold           CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     51  0
UNXSTF+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     52  0
UNXUFR+Arial-BoldMT                  CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     53  0
```

After Merging, this happens:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
SRWYVL+HelveticaLTCom-Roman          CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    420  0
SRXAHX+HelveticaLTCom-Bold           CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    421  0
SRXBUJ+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    422  0
SRXDGV+Arial-BoldMT                  CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    423  0
Helvetica-Bold                       Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  no     424  0
SRWYVL+HelveticaLTCom-Roman          CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    425  0
SRXAHX+HelveticaLTCom-Bold           CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    426  0
SRXBUJ+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    427  0
SRXDGV+Arial-BoldMT                  CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    428  0
SRWYVL+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    429  0
SRXAHX+HelveticaLTCom-Roman          CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    430  0
SRXBUJ+HelveticaLTCom-Bold           CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    431  0
SRXDGV+Arial-BoldMT                  CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    432  0
WDEGAT+Arial-BoldMT                  TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes    436  0
GSEDXU+ArialMT                       TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes    437  0
Arial                                TrueType          WinAnsi          yes no  no     416  0
ZapfDingbats                         TrueType          WinAnsi          yes no  yes    419  0
ArialNarrow                          TrueType          WinAnsi          yes no  no     417  0
ACHRDX+ZapfDingbats                  TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes    618  0
ACHRDX+ZapfDingbats                  TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes    619  0
ACHRDX+ZapfDingbats                  TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes    620  0
ACHRDX+ZapfDingbats                  TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes    621  0
ACHRDX+ZapfDingbats                  TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes    622  0
GSEDXU+ArialNarrow-Bold              TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes    560  0
NVGLHQ+ArialNarrow                   TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes    561  0
KWHHMM+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    578  0
```

My Code in Java:

```
final PDFMergerUtility pdfMerger = new PDFMergerUtility();
            pdfMerger.setDestinationStream(outputStream);
            pdfMerger.addSources(additionalPdfStreams);
            pdfMerger.addSource(inputStreamPdDocument);
            pdfMerger.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());
```

The Problem is that an Api from a third party vendor got an Problem with this Fonts.
So : What am i doing wrong and how can i remove the unused and doubled fonts ??

Comment: Please also share the source PDF files to allow reproducing the issue. In particular I'm surprised that your test run seems to indicate that PDFBox renames embedded subsets. It is possible I missed that but I don't consider it probable.

Comment: PDFBox doesn't rename fonts. What PDFBox version do you use? Are you sure that the result file was font-analysed directly after the merge, and not after something else? Is it the correct file?

Comment: Hi, i cannot upload the PDF Files its not for the public. @TilmanHausherr : Yes, the PDF was analyzed directly after the PDFBox merged it we are using 2.0.11

Comment: Current version is 2.0.12. Can you reproduce the problem by using the command line merge utility? If yes, could you try to reproduce the problem with two non confidential PDF files?

Comment: This is easily duplicated just copy mypdf.pdf to copy of mypdf.pdf then merge them together.  They carry double fonts double images double backgrounds.

Comment: @danny117 are you offering a bounty for a solution of the original specific problem (e.g. because you are working on the same project as Skary was) or are you looking for a solution to a more generic problem? Your comment hints towards the latter. In that case, though, you should describe it more clearly, and a better choice would have been to ask an own question to start with.

Comment: The original question looks even weirder to me now: `UNTWVR+HelveticaLTCom-Roman` is in a source file, but not in the merged file. PDFBox does not change its font names when merging. Whatever the problem is, I recommend to retry with the upcoming 2.0.14 version, many merge bugs have been fixed (although none with fonts)

Comment: @mkl  I just wasn't satisfied with my merged PDFs.  Hopefully some good will come of this.  This was months old.

Answer (score 6):

The "duplication" issue seems like it's coming from multiple pages, because each page contains its own font metadata.  If you iterate over the pages and get the font names, then you will see duplicates in the output if a font is used in more than one page.

Something seems very wrong with the details in the question though.  Neither of the source files have `ZapfDingbats` font, so where did it come from into the merged document?

First, I wrote a couple of helper methods:

```
static String mergePdfs(InputStream is1, InputStream is2) throws IOException {
    PDFMergerUtility pdfMerger = new PDFMergerUtility();
    pdfMerger.addSource(is1);
    pdfMerger.addSource(is2);

    String destFile = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + System.nanoTime() + ".pdf";
    pdfMerger.setDestinationFileName(destFile);
    pdfMerger.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());

    return destFile;
}

static List<String> getFontNames(PDDocument doc) throws IOException {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i < doc.getNumberOfPages(); i++){
        PDPage page = doc.getPage(i);
        PDResources res = page.getResources();
        for (COSName fontName : res.getFontNames()) {
            result.add(res.getFont(fontName).toString());
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then I created 3 test PDF documents.  The first 2, `test-pdf-1.pdf` and `test-pdf-2.pdf` contain one page each and use the same two fonts: `PDTrueTypeFont BAAAAA+ArialMT` and `PDTrueTypeFont CAAAAA+Roboto-Black`.  The 3rd one, `test-pdf-3.pdf`, contains 2 pages from the first two documents, and was created with a text editor and not with PDFBox.

And then added the following test code:

```
Class clazz = Test.class;
String src1, src2, src3;
src1 = "/test-pdf-1.pdf";
src2 = "/test-pdf-2.pdf";
src3 = "/test-pdf-3.pdf";

InputStream is1, is2, is3;
is1 = clazz.getResourceAsStream(src1);
is2 = clazz.getResourceAsStream(src2);

String merged = mergePdfs(is1, is2);

PDDocument doc1, doc2, doc3, doc4;

is1 = clazz.getResourceAsStream(src1);
doc1 = PDDocument.load(is1);

is2 = clazz.getResourceAsStream(src2);
doc2 = PDDocument.load(is2);

is3 = clazz.getResourceAsStream(src3);
doc3 = PDDocument.load(is3);

doc4 = PDDocument.load(new File(merged));

System.out.println(src1 + " >\n\t" + getFontNames(doc1));
System.out.println(src2 + " >\n\t" + getFontNames(doc2));
System.out.println(src3 + " >\n\t" + getFontNames(doc3));
System.out.println(merged  + " >\n\t" + getFontNames(doc4));
```

The output is as follows (I truncated the last file name for readability and easier comparison):

```
/test-pdf-1.pdf >
[PDTrueTypeFont BAAAAA+ArialMT, PDTrueTypeFont CAAAAA+Roboto-Black]
/test-pdf-2.pdf >
[PDTrueTypeFont BAAAAA+ArialMT, PDTrueTypeFont CAAAAA+Roboto-Black]
/test-pdf-3.pdf >
[PDTrueTypeFont BAAAAA+ArialMT, PDTrueTypeFont CAAAAA+Roboto-Black, PDTrueTypeFont BAAAAA+ArialMT, PDTrueTypeFont CAAAAA+Roboto-Black]
C:\Temp\..9.pdf >
[PDTrueTypeFont BAAAAA+ArialMT, PDTrueTypeFont CAAAAA+Roboto-Black, PDTrueTypeFont BAAAAA+ArialMT, PDTrueTypeFont CAAAAA+Roboto-Black]
```

You can see that both the file created by PDFBox's merge, "C:\temp\7193671804393899.pdf" (abbreviated in the output for readability), and the file "test-pdf-3.pdf" which was created with an editor have the same output for fonts, showing each font twice, one for each page.

Opening the merged file in Acrobat Reader confirms that only one copy of the fonts exists:

[image: C:\temp\7193671804393899.pdf Properties > Fonts]

Comment: Your code gets only the top level resources. There could be more fonts in form xobjects, in field widgets, etc. Btw if you'd use the result as a set and not as a list you'd eliminate the duplicates.

Comment: The intent here was to address the question specifically so using a Set would have defeated the purpose.  I created the test documents so I know that there are no forms etc.  I kept the code as simple as possible for clarity and readability.

Comment: If you could Save as from acrobat on the merged pdf and see if the file size gets smaller.  That's my biggest issue.  Thanks

Comment: @danny117 The file size created by PDFBox merge as detailed above is: `32.7 KB (33,519 bytes)`.  I opened it in Acrobat Reader and did Save As, the saved result is actually larger at `36.1 KB (37,000 bytes)`.

Comment: Who figure that it would be larger.  That's my main concern is my merged file is so much larger than it should be.  Thanks again

Comment: @danny117 I am guessing that it depends on the input file. To clarify, my PDFBox-merged PDF is actually smaller than when I open and re-save it with Acrobat Reader.  My two original files are 1-page each, and the merged file is a 2-pager.  Did you try with the upcoming PDFBox 2.0.14 as Tilman suggested in the comments of the question?

Comment: Thanks for all your help on this.

Comment: Thank you @danny117.  You can contact me on LinkedIn if you're there.  My contact information is on my profile.

Answer (score 0):

The Merge Program is giving its own replacement fonts as it cant  find or use the existing fonts embedded in Pdf.
You have to rewrite code and use the specific font .
extract all fonts from pdf 
Then merge them make sure you use the same font.

Try using system fonts that should not cause any issue to third party
Custom  fonts are always an issue.
Some API does not take any unsigned fonts.

Check this font 
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID

---

XXMGEM+Arial-BoldMT                  TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     15  0

This font was in first file but after combining them this font is missing.

Comment: Are you sure your answering the correct question? Your answer appears to have nothing to do with the question here...

Comment: I think so .Can you see this was font in first pdf file.name .                                type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
XXMGEM+Arial-BoldMT                  TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     15  0  and this font is not found in combined pdf file.

Comment: @ mkl  the problem is not unused fonts or duplicate fonts . the problem is third party api whcih cannot read it .